# Dúvidas criação, manipulação e eliminação de form

Tags: delphi

Possuo as seguintes dúvidas:

- Ao criar um form, conforme o código abaixo, preciso destruir ele de alguma maneira quando o mesmo for finalizado pelo usuário?

F_PesqCli := TF_PesqCli.Create(self);

F_PesqCli.ShowModal;

- Como garantir que uma janela não seja aberta duplamente?
- Como faço para minimizar um form internamente, como no exemplo da imagem abaixo?

[image: Form minimizado]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Como garantir a liberação do form da memória?

> Ao criar um form, conforme o código abaixo, preciso destruir ele de alguma maneira quando o mesmo for finalizado pelo usuário?
>
> `F_PesqCli := TF_PesqCli.Create(self);`

O construtor `Create` padrão dos objetos `TComponent` no delphi recebe por parâmetro `(AOwner: TComponent)`

Se você passa o `Owner` como `Self`, você está dizendo que a instância atual de onde o código está é a **dona** do componente criado, no caso o `TForm`. Sendo assim, quando esse **Dono** for destruído, o form também será.

Se você quer que, quando o usuário finalizar um form, que ele seja destruído, no evento `onClose` do form basta você setar a ação desejada

```
Action := caFree;
```

Outra medida é gerenciar o ciclo de vida as janelas `Modal` durante a inicialização delas:

```
Form := TForm.Create(nil);
try
  Form.ShowModal;
finally
  Form.Free;
end;
```

### 2. Como garantir que uma janela não seja aberta duplamente?

A maneira mais segura é validar nos já criados na aplicação

```
function ValidaFormJaCriado(const ClassDoForm: TClass): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  for I := 0 to Screen.FormCount - 1 do
  begin
    if Screen.Forms[I].Class = ClassDoForm then
    begin
      Result := True;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

### 3. Como faço para minimizar um form internamente, como no exemplo da imagem abaixo?

O Form Principal deve ser setada a propriedade `FormStyle` para `fsMDIForm`
Os forms filhos devem ter o form pai como Owner e `FormStyle` para `fsMDIChild`

Comment: Perfeito, era exatamente isso que eu precisava. Muito obrigado